# Python UnicodeEncodeError with pre decoded UTF-8

Tags: python, parsing, unicode, encoding, decoding

I'm trying to parse through a bunch of logfiles (up to 4GiB) in a tar.gz file. The source files come from RedHat 5.8 Server systems and SunOS 5.10, processing has to be done on WindowsXP.

I iterate through the tar.gz files, read the files, decode the file contents to UTF-8 and parse them with regular expressions before further processing.

When I'm writing out the processed data along with the raw-data that was read from the tar.gz, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\WoMMaxX\lt_automation\Tools\LogParser.py", line 375, in <module>
    p.analyze_longtails()
  File "C:\WoMMaxX\lt_automation\Tools\LogParser.py", line 196, in analyze_longtails
    oFile.write(entries[key]['source'] + '\n')
  File "C:\Python\3.2\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 24835-24836: character maps
to <undefined>
```

Heres the part where I read and parse the logfiles:

```
def getSalesSoaplogEntries(perfid=None):                
        for tfile in parser.salestarfiles:
            path = os.path.join(parser.logpath,tfile)            
            if os.path.isfile(path):
                if tarfile.is_tarfile(path):
                    tar = tarfile.open(path,'r:gz')
                    for tarMember in tar.getmembers():
                        if 'salescomponent-soap.log' in tarMember.name:
                            tarMemberFile = tar.extractfile(tarMember)
                            content = tarMemberFile.read().decode('UTF-8','surrogateescape')

                            for m in parser.soaplogregex.finditer(content):
                                entry = {}
                                entry['time'] = datetime(datetime.now().year, int(m.group('month')), int(m.group('day')),int(m.group('hour')), int(m.group('minute')), int(m.group('second')), int(m.group('millis'))*1000)
                                entry['perfid'] = m.group('perfid')
                                entry['direction'] = m.group('direction')
                                entry['payload'] = m.group('payload')
                                entry['file'] = tarMember.name
                                entry['source'] = m.group(0)
                                sm = parser.soaplogmethodregex.match(entry['payload'])
                                if sm:
                                    entry['method'] = sm.group('method')

                                    if entry['time'] >= parser.starttime and entry['time'] <= parser.endtime:
                                        if perfid and entry['perfid'] == perfid:
                                            yield entry
                        tar.members = []
```

And heres the part where I write the processed information along with the raw data out(its an aggregation of all log-entries for one specific process:

```
if len(entries) > 0:
    time = perfentry['time']
    filename = time.isoformat('-').replace(':','').replace('-','') + 'longtail_' + perfentry['perfid'] + '.txt'
    oFile = open(os.path.join(parser.logpath,filename), 'w')
    oFile.write(perfentry['source'] +'\n')
    oFile.write('------\n')
    for key in sorted(entries.keys()):
        oFile.write('------\n')
        oFile.write(entries[key]['source'] + '\n') #<-- here it is failing
```

What I don't get is why it seems to be correct to read the files in UTF-8, it is not possible to just write them out as UTF-8. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The traceback would indicate you're not trying to encode them as UTF-8, but as cp1252.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output file is using the default encoding for your OS, which is *not* UTF-8. Use `codecs.open` instead of `open` and specify `encoding='utf-8'`.

```
oFile = codecs.open(os.path.join(parser.logpath,filename), 'w', encoding='utf-8')
```

See http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data